Trouble evaluating a complex expression
Calculate $\left(\sqrt2+i\right)^i$
My solution:
$\left(\sqrt2+i\right)^i=\left(2^\frac{1}{2}+e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}\right)^i=2^{\frac{1}{2}i}+e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i^2}=2^{\frac{1}{2}i}+e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$
However i am not sure how to proceed from here.

You're assuming $(x+y)^i=x^i+y^i$, which is nonsense.

You made a mistake in your workings. To illustrate your mistake, $(a+b)^2$ is not equivalent to $a^2 + b^2$
$\sqrt{2}+i = \sqrt{3}e^{i \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}$
Hence:
$(\sqrt{2}+i)^i = (\sqrt{3})^i(e^{-\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})})$
Now $(\sqrt{3})^i = e^{i \ln(\sqrt{3})} = \cos(\ln(\sqrt{3})) + i\sin(\ln(\sqrt{3}))$
So
$(\sqrt{2}+i)^i = \cos(\frac{1}{2}\ln(3))(e^{-\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})})+ i\sin(\frac{1}{2}\ln(3))(e^{-\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})})$
$\approx 0.461 + 0.282i$

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Bear in mind it's multi-valued.

How was the equivalent expression derived. Could you provide some pointers. Thank you in advance.
